# Liquor making with Time related magic in an ancient-medieval world

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, food, time-manipulation

So you can accelerate or reverse time of an inanimate/non sentient  object within a limited space.

Despite having such powers, you don't want to rule the world. Instead you want to make alcoholic drinks.

Assuming you have only basic knowledge of making liquor of all kinds, how will your time related magic make you really good at making alcoholic drinks?

Additionally, how to become filthy rich in making liquors?

Comment: Buy a vineyard. Use your time warping magic on the vineyard, making it produce a full crop of ripe grapes daily. This will increase the output of your winery 365 times, with a corresponding increase in profit. If you are mischievous, you could also work your time warping magic on the competing wineries, making *their* vineyards produce a crop of grapes once every century; this will give you monopoly power. (Note: this is not an answer. This is exquisitely subtle criticism intended to make the querent think again about their question.)

Comment: @AlexP wont that degrade the land fertility at a really astonishing rate?

Comment: *"Degrade the land fertility:"* How so? Isn't the soil also a *"inanimate/non sentient object"*, subject the time warping magic? In the end, all this does is accelerate the exhaustion of the Sun's nuclear fusion fuel, but only a little.

Comment: @AlexP yes it is but the nutrients inside the soil is limited. By continuously harvesting grapes through time accelerations,  land is degraded further and further due to high nutrients/minerals needed for continuous production of the fruit due to intensive use of time magic. Nutrients/minerals are not being restored/resupplied on the land(Nitrogen Cycle), Sure it can be done with fertilizer but over application will result on a degraded product or simply lack of other nutrients needed for a proper/prime grapes to be harvested and used for production.

Comment: *"Nutrients/minerals are not being restored/resupplied on the land":* of course they are. The nitrogen (and phosphorus, never forget the phosphorus) restoration is simply to be accelerated as needed. There are many vineyards in Europe more than four centuries old; since in our non-magical world a vineyard can survive four centuries, it follows that the soil can regenerate over four hundred cycles. (Bonus: there is [vine in Slovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%BDametovka) which is *itself* 400 years old.)

Comment: @AlexP thank you for that info, i can modify my scenario and resolve alot of my dilemma due to that information

Comment: I would suggest you study wine making, wine selling, and vineyards a bit more because [old wine is not always better and most wine is drank within 5 years of bottling](https://www.marketviewliquor.com/blog/2016/04/dont-make-these-top-wine-mistakes-wine-myths-debunked-and-common-wine-drinking-mistakes/) - and there is a whole host of questions one would have to ask about PH balances and other soil conditions if we start "speeding up or slowing down" the vines themselves. (actually whiskey and other barrel aged drinks might bea better fit for this type of magic)

Comment: @JGreenwell i see, so wine isnt like whiskey or brandy that when aged for a long time using time magic will be better?

Comment: Wine will benefit from aging (depending on the wine and aging process) and vines can certainly give better yields in later years - but that's not how you make money with wine. It comes from building a name, even if your wine is the best ever and worth $170 a bottle - nobody will pay that because nobody knows your vineyard. With aged liquors there is a huge difference in quality due to aging but the effect would be minimal with this power too ("aged 40 years"....but I just saw you put that in the barrels yesterday you liar! & you have to switch barrels at certain points, monitor closely, etc)

Comment: We can solve the problem @micovillena brings up on alexp's comment by allowing 2 days between crops instead daily. Yes, the soil must be replenished.  You accomplish this by top dressing the soil with compost, made from waste from vine trimming & pomace from pressing the grapes. Plus additional compost and minerals if needed. It doesn't sound like we can speed up the labor, so give a day to make the compost (speeding up the decomposition)  Labor is for collecting, turning, & spreading (can use machinery for some of that). Also speed up compost breakdown in the soil, worms, & microbes.

Comment: While you're speeding up time, does that also increase the solar radiation which reaches the location? For instance, with the example in comments of increasing the yield of grapes by 365x, unless the energy input during the sped-up time increases by 365x, then the grape vines are just going to die.

Comment: See my answer below. I work in a vineyard all the time. You are out there every day working in it. Starting and stopping time to work in the vineyard would be more work than it's worth. Making booze is a much easier method to make money. Buy grain, ferment and turn into pure alcohol. It's all in the barrel aging. For that reason alone, wine would be a non starter.

Answer (score 11):

Making aged wine would be simpler than aged liquor.

Both wine and liquor can benefit from the ageing process. However, producing aged liquor (brandy, whiskey etc.) is technologically more complex and depends on the expertise of the distiller.

I recommend the following approach:

1. After the harvest, when young wine starts to hit the market, buy
   samples of cheap wine from all around your region. The quality would
   be mostly mediocre, but each wine would age differently.
2. Age all the samples for several years (wine time). Then open them up and invite a sommelier for a tasting session. Among your samples, some likely would be real hits.
3. Proceed to buy all supplies of young wine that would turn
   into a "hit". Age the winners, present them at professional wine
   events, and prepare for a lot of orders.

You can do essentially the same for liquors, but the process would be more complicated.

P.S. In premium liquors, manufacturers strive not just for an exceptional taste, but for the stability of it, meaning that they want to produce essentially the same taste for the range of years. In wines, no two years are the same. Restaurants would go for a good no-name wine, but not for a no-name liquor (even if taste is great).

P.P.S. If we focus on the **ancient** world, then if you character happens to know how to distill wine, he's all set for brisk business. Liquor was invented only in medieval times.

Answer (score 6):

**This arrangement buys you one thing only: you're always first to market**

Which isn't enough to guarantee wealth.  Here's the deal:

- Wine requires a nice grape - which has nothing to do with your magic.
- Wine requires a nice environment - which has nothing to do with your magic.
- Wine requires correct storage - which has nothing to do with your magic.
- Wine requires time to ferment - this has to do with your magic.

In other words, you have all the same problems of every other oenologist, but you can speed up the fermentation process (age the wine more quickly from the perspective of the wizard's reference frame).

And that means you can get it to market faster.  But you don't have any more of it and you still need everything else to make good wine and one you've sold your lot — you're done making money.

**What about bank interest?**

No, not really a solution to the problem.  Yes, you're getting the money into the bank sooner, but that's a benefit for only the first deposit.  Every deposit after that occurs exactly one year later because you still need to grow the grapes, etc.  So, you make a couple of extra bucks on the fist deposit's interest, but that's it.

**OK, but being first to market must count for something, doesn't it?**

No, not really, because everybody else is out there still making wine.  They may be taking the traditional route — but there's still their wine to be purchased.  They could always release last-year's wine in competition with your wine this year.

**So, how do I make an absolutely offensive amount of money with wine?**

1. Your magic multiplies the *amount* of wine you have so that you have more wine to sell.
2. Your magic improves the *quality* of the wine so you can sell it for more than your competitors.

Comment: I see, but just a question, if i change the wine into brandy/whiskey instead will i be able to sell it more than my competitors since i can age it faster than anyone around? I mean i could theoretically age it to a century or a millennia

Comment: @micovillena, no.  You have the same problem.  You haven't changed the quality nor the quantity.  All you can do is mature it faster.  That might buy you something as thirsty footballers are happy to soak in whatever you can deliver - but once you're out of stock, you're out of stock.  To think about it another way, you're manufacturing a widget in California and selling it in Texas.  The only thing you've changed is the transport time between the two locations.  You can't manufacture more or better  than you already can, you just don't have to wait as long before you sell it.

Answer (score 3):

I have quite a bit of experience in the Beer/Wine/Alcohol industry and here is my take. (Check out my reputation on [alcohol.stackexchange.com](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/6111/farmersteve))

Wine could benefit from aging at two points, especially red wine. Barrel aging which can be up to 2-3 years in the barrel, then bottle aging, which can go on for 20+ years depending on the quality of the red wine. White wine only benefits from extended aging for a handful of years.

There are exceptions to this. Madeira and Port which can benefit from aging in the bottle for decades and the price goes up as they get older and older. I tasted a 200 year old Madeira a couple of years ago. Bottles were going for over $10,000 so that could be a way to reap the benefits.

The problem with wine is that it's once a year during grape harvest.

Booze can be made continuously as long as you have a supply of grain. Barrel aging Whisky enhances the value quite a bit and the longer it's in the barrel, the more valuable it gets. You would have to do some maintenance on the barrels of booze, topping up every few months so you would need to start and stop time. Whisky does not age once it's in the bottle, unlike wine.

Whisky is really probably where the money would be under this scheme because of the continuous nature of distilling booze. You could age a batch of Whisky every day to like 50 years and just repeat the process every day when you distilled more booze.

Answer (score 2):

I never did the wine, but I made some homebrew whiskey and cognac. One secret you should know is that waiting for many years is not mandatory. Commercial production does it because it is convenient for them to do so: make a big barrel, put it in the cellar, forget for ten years.
When you make a small amount for yourself and friends, you use 5 liters barrel and you need to wait only for 4 month max. The time depends on the size of the barrel, or, to be more precise, on the ratio of inner surface to liquid volume. Or you can even speed up further by agitating the barrel regularly.
I even thought to use chemical ceramic magnetic mixer, but did not get to do it.

Comment: This might be OK on [homebrew.se], given the right question.

Comment: This is good information but the question was about how to profit from manipulating time in the liquor business.  Your notes should be a comment on the question or on an answer that assumes things about aging liquor.  Or you can expand your answer to answer the question.  ("Aging doesn't work like you think because XYZ, but here's what you can do instead to use your power to make money.")

Answer (score 0):

> So you can (...) reverse time of an inanimate/non sentient object (...).

Ditch ordinary wine, that is just fermented grape juice that doesn't give you anything magical.

User your powers to make [Ghlen Livid from the Discworld](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Reannual_plant), a drink that gives you glimpses of the future:

> Reannual plants are an unusual sort of flora native to the Disc. It works like this: **when a farmer plants a reannual this year, the plant is harvested last year**. There are several challenges involved in doing so: for one, if you forget to sow the seeds after you harvest them, you risk disturbing the entire fabric of causality (although, as mentioned in Mort, causality is stronger than most people think). Thus, it takes farmers who are much given to introspection and close examination of the calendar (...), to pull it off correctly.
>
> (...) The reannual Vul Nuts are mentioned in The Colour of Magic as being grown in the latter place, and when harvested they make a drink called Ghlen Livid. Mort's family specializes in making wine from reannual grapes, which cause their own problems, as you have the hangover the morning before, and have to drink quite a lot to get over it.
>
> (...) Ghlen Livid is a spirit made from the freeze distilled Vul Nut, a reannual plant. **Reannuals travel back in time**, so Ghlen Livid **can give its drinkers a vision of the future, which is, from the nut's point of view, the past**.

A hangover from such spirits is called a hangunder. No one knows what happens if you have a hangunder and are prevented from drinking afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

Out of season products.

Lots of comments on how to improve the actual brewing process, but what about the ingredients?  You can get end-of-season grapes or hops - perhaps a delayed shipment from overseas - then *reverse time* for the produce to restore it to prime condition.  Not all brewings/fermentations are designed to be aged, and you can serve these "Fresh" examples at *any* time of year.

Any fruit that is requires transportation is (certainly in *modern* times) picked before it is properly ripe, and then allowed to ripen in-transit.  This has a noticeable impact on the taste of the end result.