# Doing business with time magic in ancient-medieval world

Tags: magic, economy, time-manipulation

What business could I in theory do if I have Time magic which can reverse or accelerate time of inanimate/non sentient objects in a limited area?

This is in relation to my question,

[Liquor making with Time related magic in an ancient-medieval world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/139251/liquor-making-with-time-related-magic-in-an-ancient-medieval-world)

First thing came to my mind with this scheme is liquor making since it needs aging.

However I don't know any other applications of this magic when it comes to doing business apart from the following.

- Preservation
- Aging

If you could suggest a product or business where I will be the only producer, that would be appreciated, or at least one where the production is really limited during these times.

Comment: This sounds kind of like a "let's do some brainstorming!" request rather than a question seeking to address a problem or issue with time magic.  Please edit accordingly! Also, you've got too many questions going on here: one is the brainstorming request (other applications) and the other is the overly broad "what business".  A broad query can basically be answered by the simple word **anything**.  This is why the SE model is one question dealing with one problem or issue gets one clear answer. VTC

Comment: I have to agree it's too brainstormy, though I get the impulse.  I'd also like to see you clarify "inanimate/non sentient objects."  Raising livestock for market would be a good way to make money; they are non-sentient but are they "objects?"  Raising sheep or cashmere goats as well, so their hair/wool grows back in a day instead of a couple times a year.  Agriculture too, but you got that in the wine question.  There's just too much here.  What the heck, I'll answer anyway.

Comment: How bout asking what business would not benefit from time magic? So far I can only think of jellyfish farm since they are truly biologically immortal as one such species called itself Turritopsis dohrnii can reverse aging. To other readers: Top that!

Comment: `Time magic which can reverse or accelerate time of inanimate/non sentient objects in a limited area` - does this exclude plants.  I was thinking I could use it in my herb garden .... :-)~

Answer (score 2):

**Restoration of ancient items**

Books and scrolls fade over time and the parchment can become brittle. Reversing time for really important items such as treaties between countries and trade agreements or other legal documents especially signed ones. You could also reverse out mold or water damage.

The only other option is to get scribes to make copies and for signed documents, that may not be an option thus you'd be the only choice.

Comment: That's a terrific idea.  I didn't even think of that.  I wonder if it would work to restore fire or water damaged items...

Answer (score 2):

## Pearls

Grow [pearls](https://rawpearls.com.au/pearl_knowledge).  Oysters take [upwards of 7 years](https://www.pearl-guide.com/forum/showthread.php?1170-How-long-time-for-a-pearl-of-size) to grow pearls.  Culture them.

### A few other ideas:

Livestock are non-sentient.  Raise chicks to a size ready to lay eggs or become meat.  Reverse time on laying hens so they have a longer productive life.

Raise mammals to slaughter size or milking age.  Reverse time on milking animals to allow them to "freshen" without having to give birth (in real life, a cow or other milk animal must birth every 1-2 years to keep her milk production going).  Or speed up gestation.

Raise sheep and cashmere goats so they produce hair/wool quickly.  Since lambswool is more valuable than regular wool, reverse time so that's what they always produce.  Speed up the process so they need sheering every day instead of a couple times a year.  Or set the timing so that all their hair growth is while they're being kept indoors very clean.  Cleaning wool is a pain in the neck and it's hard to keep sheep that clean for months.

Make cheese.  Very fancy cheeses need to age for a while but the real problem is figuring out the right methods to make them just so.  You could cut down your research and development stage to days.

Cashmere goats are not common but their hair is quite valuable.  You could also raise unusual sheep for their wool.  Or other animals like camels.

Grow tulips.  There was [a tulip craze](https://www.britannica.com/event/Tulip-Mania) in Europe in the early 17th century.  It got so bad that people went into debt just for a single bulb which they hoped to reproduce and make their fortune with.  Needless to say, the market crashed and it was hellish.  You could get ahold of some bulbs of tulips or other flowers and reproduce them.  If your best bulbs die, reverse time and try again.

Grow other valuable plants and sell them *or* go to people's estates and speed up growth of their plants.  For example, a [wisteria vine](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/long-before-wisteria-plant-blooms-first-time-69737.html) can take up to 15 years before it blooms.  [Saguaro cactus](https://www.desertmuseum.org/kids/oz/long-fact-sheets/Saguaro%20Cactus.php) take decades to be a reasonable size and to branch.  In the modern world they can add tens of thousands of years to the value of a home.  (Note that you never said *where* you lived in your world.)

Even microgreens can grow in minutes instead of days, then grow some out to seed to replant.  If there's a market for them, you will dominate it.

If you want to get super fancy, [create gemstones](https://www.gemrockauctions.com/learn/technical-information-on-gemstones/how-do-gemstones-form).  These take special conditions, the ability to know where they will occur, and enough finesse that you don't screw up your world.

Comment: inanimate/non sentient objects means nothing living which limits the use greatly

Comment: @Thorne except the OP has stated that fermentation counts (it's alive) and accepted answers on the other post about vineyards and the like, which are also living.  I don't know if the statement is just badly worded or...

Comment: It's badly worded

Comment: @Cyn Livestock animals are most definitely sentient. The word you're probably thinking of is _sapient_.